# Transform an object to list of lists in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

I am making an API call from Angular 5, the response is coming in below format.

```
{   "metadata":{
      "lastSyncTime":"2000-11-21T16:07:53",
      "dataFromDB":true
   },
   "allocationReports":[      {
         "allocatedUserCount":100,
         "healthGoalName":"Eat Healthier"
      },
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":130,
         "healthGoalName":"Feel Happier"
      },
  
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":150,
         "healthGoalName":"Quit Smoking"
      }
   ],
   "overall":{
      "usersWithGoalCount":0,
      "registeredCount":500,
      "eligibleCount":280
   }
}
```

I need to transform this data into a list of lists(or Array of Arrays) so that I can plot multiple donut charts on this data. I have tried with multiple methods like using .map, but getting all the values in single list. How can I build the data in below format.

The required format is :

```
[ 
 [
  { "x": "Eat Healthier", "y": 100 },
  { "x": "Total registered", "y": 500 } 
 ],
 [
  { "x": "Feel Happier", "y": 130 },
  { "x": "Total registered", "y": 500 } 
 ],
 [
  { "x": "Quit Smoking", "y": 150 },
  { "x": "Total registered", "y": 500 } 
 ]
]
```

The total registered value will come from `overall.registeredCount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
ob={"metadata":{ "lastSyncTime":"2000-11-21T16:07:53", "dataFromDB":true }, "allocationReports":[      { "allocatedUserCount":100, "healthGoalName":"Eat Healthier" }, { "allocatedUserCount":130, "healthGoalName":"Feel Happier" }, { "allocatedUserCount":150, "healthGoalName":"Quit Smoking" } ], "overall":{ "usersWithGoalCount":0, "registeredCount":500, "eligibleCount":280 } }

r=ob.allocationReports.map(o=>{return [{x:o.healthGoalName,y:o.allocatedUserCount},{x: "Total registered", y: ob.overall.registeredCount }]})

console.log(r)
```

Comment: One more question, if you can help please. Can we sort the resultant array in ascending of order "allocatedUserCount" .